# Error message: unable to mount location Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, mount, hard-drive

When trying to open the internal hard drive, the error message:

> unable to mount location, can't mount file appears.

Note: Ubuntu was installed over windows

Comment: What is the complete and *exact* text of the error message? And what are you doing to try to access the drive? Is this a separate drive from the one you installed Ubuntu on with Wubi? Or are you trying to access the drive on which you installed Wubi? If you're trying to access the Windows partition in which you installed Wubi, that's automatically mounted at `/host`. Are you not able to access it there?

Answer (score -1):

Probably its because Windows uses NTFS partition, so , you need install ntfs-3g for access to location sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g

Comment: Ubuntu comes with `ntfs-3g` already installed. (Theoretically it could be uninstalled but this is likely; if you're concerned that it was uninstalled, I recommend editing your answer to clarify that.)